# Visual Studio 2017 Bulk Class adder

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I plan out my projects using UML. So, when it comes time to actually write the code, I spend a good chunk of time adding a bunch of class files. I've become fairly quick at this process, but I feel like it could be improved (and VS 2017 may have some tools to help).

Right now, the way I do it is:

```
1- Ctrl+Shift+A -> add new item
2- (it's usually already specified the template I'd like to use, so I don't have to search for it. 
3- Shift+Tab x3 -> to move the selection to the name of the class
4- Type the name
5- Enter
```

While this is fairly quick, I'd like to know if there is some kind of tool within Visual Studio, that lets you add a lot of classes in quick succession. Preferably:

```
(asks you for the first class name)
1- type the class name
2- Enter
(asks you for the second class name.. repeat)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with [Add New File extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.AddNewFile), which could use Shift + F2 shortcut to add file quickly.

And you also could not to choose file type every time. You just need to type the file suffix behind the file name when adding files.